# How to look up the type of resource behind a URI?

Tags: rest, uri

I'm trying to design a REST API where:

1. A client issues HTTP DELETE `/users/5`.
2. The operation fails with `HTTP 409 ("CONFLICT")`, the `Location` header points at the dependent resources that must be deleted first (e.g. bug reports created by the user). I am choosing not to automatically cascade the delete.

Because the `HTTP 409 ("CONFLICT")` response may point at multiple types of resources, I need a way for clients to look up the type of resource that was returned (to ensure the system understands what is being deleted, instead of propgating deletes willy-nilly).

What's the appropriate course of action? Is there a way for the client to enumerate the available `Content-Type`s of a URI? Should the client invoke `HTTP HEAD` WITH `Accept: */*` and compare the resulting `Content-Type` against a list of known types?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is a little bit hinky. The spec only suggests the Location header for use with 201 and 3xx responses. In addition, the 409 (Conflict) response says:

> In this case, the response representation would likely contain
> information useful for merging the differences based on the revision
> history.
>      -- [RFC 7231, Section 6.5.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)

Sounds to me like they advocate using the entity to explain the conflict, and not the Location header.

Comment: That is not exactly true. The sentence you quoted applies to the specific example they are discussing. If you read above (for the general case) they write: `The server SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user to recognize the source of the conflict.` The `payload` does not refer to the body alone. It also includes the headers. So to recap, there is nothing wrong with using the `Location` header.

That being said, are you suggesting that I use the response body to return both a `Content-Type` and a `URI` at once?

Comment: @Gili The text of the Location header (7.1.2) talks about 201 and 3xx responses, but not any others. I didn't say it was Wrong, just hinky. There are no IANA-registered headers (http://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml) that allow for Location-Content-Type. I am not a fan of custom headers because intermediaries are allowed to strip them. If you can afford the HEAD call, I think that's more Correct than the payload body route, but most of my clients would balk at the extra call.

Comment: Is `HEAD` allowed to return `HTTP 303 ("Multiple Choices")` if you omit the `Accept` header? Perhaps this better than `Accept: */*` which will returns one of many representations...